# Spatial Poisson process of discs and the $r \rightarrow 0$ limit

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, poisson-process

Consider a (homogeneous) spatial Poisson process $\Pi$ in $[0,1]^2$ with constant rate $\lambda^2$. For each $x \in \Pi$, let $D_x$ be the disc centered at $x$ with radius $r$, and let $D = \bigcup_{x \in \Pi} D_x$ be the union of all disks.

We couple $r$ and $\lambda$ such that $\pi r^2 \lambda^2 = \varepsilon$ for some $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$ fixed, so that the (approximate) expected area of $D \cap [0,1]^2$ is constant ($\pi r^2$ is the area of one disk and $\lambda^2$ is the expected number of points in $\Pi$).

I am interested in the $r \rightarrow 0$ (equivalently, $\lambda \rightarrow \infty$) limit of this process. In particular, I suspect that the indicator function $1_{D \cap [0,1]^2}$ of the region $D$ in $[0,1]^2$ tends to the constant function $\varepsilon$ in the limit, in the weak sense. That is, in the limit the collection of disks $D$ end up 'blanketing' the space $[0,1]^2$ with density $\varepsilon$.

I am unsure if this is an established property in the literature and do not know how to go about proving this. We can upper-bound $\text{Area}(D)$ by $|\Pi|\cdot \pi r^2$, which tends to $\varepsilon$ in the limit, but I cannot get anything more.

Comment: It is true that the weak limit of $\mathbf{1}_{D\cap[0,1]^2}$ is a constant function, but the constant value is $1-e^{-\varepsilon}$ and not $\varepsilon$. (As a sanity check, note that if $\varepsilon > 1$ then the limiting constant value still cannot exceed $1$.)

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you could let us know exactly which function space you're working on when discussing weak convergence. I believe that the weak convergence for $\mathbf{1}_{D\cap[0,1]^2}$ should work out in the space $L^0([0,1)^2,\text{Leb})$ of finite random fields endowed with the topology of convergence in probability, but spelling this out would clear up any potential confusion.

Comment: @SangchulLee I am interested in any notion of convergence which works; if there is a proof for convergence in probability in the space you have described then I would be interested in seeing it. It is also an interesting question to ask if this convergence can be upgraded to, say, almost-sure convergence.